# ionic-plugin-keyboard show/hide events not working on blackberry10

Tags: cordova, keyboard, ionic-framework, blackberry-10

I want to use the `ionic-plugin-keyboard` plugin on my `blackberry10` platform target. I had to figure out that nothing happens in respect to the event listener below.

```
window.addEventListener('native.keyboardshow', keyboardShowHandler);
window.addEventListener('native.keyboardhide', keyboardHideHandler);

function keyboardShowHandler(e){
    alert('Keyboard height is: ' + e.keyboardHeight);
}

function keyboardHideHandler(e){
    alert('Goodnight, sweet prince');
}
```

The event listener are never called as well as the implemented alerts...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While debugging the code with `Web Inspector` I found out, that the related `blackberry10` plugin code is missing in my `blackberry10` mobile application. I am assuming that the corresponding code gets never parsed into the `blackberry10` platform target from `cordova`.

As a possible workaround I am using these events now, which I have found on the `WebWorks 2.2` documentation on the blackberry developer page ([show](https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/apis/v2_2/blackberry.app.html#jbo1385148770623) / [hide](https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/apis/v2_2/blackberry.app.html#jbo1385148771390)):

```
document.addEventListener( "keyboardOpened", keyboardShowHandler );
document.addEventListener( "keyboardClosed", keyboardHideHandler );
```

These events are available by adding the `com.blackberry.app` plugin to the `cordova` project:

```
cordova plugin add com.blackberry.app
```